# The axiom of infinity for Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory

Tags: set-theory, axioms

The axiom of infinity for Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory is stated as follows in [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#7._Axiom_of_infinity):

> Let $S(w)$ abbreviate $ w \cup \{w\} $, where $ w $ is some set (We can see that $\{w\}$ is a valid set by applying the Axiom of Pairing with $ x=y=w $ so that the set $z$ is $\{w\} $). Then there exists a set $X$ such that the empty set $\varnothing$ is a member of $X$ and, whenever a set $y$ is a member of $X$, then $S(y)$ is also a member of $X$.

I don't understand the intuition behind the set $ w \cup \{w\} $. Why this causes the set $X$ to be infinite ? I think $ \{w\} $ is enough.

Comment: Natural numbers may provide the intuition: $0:=\emptyset,1:=\{0\}=S(\emptyset), 2:=\{0,1\}=S(1), 3:=\{0,1,2\}=S(2)\cdots$.

Comment: Asaf vs B.M.S${}$

Comment: "I think $\{w\}$ is enough." The problem with defining $S(w)=\{w\}$ is that we cannot have an infinite set without violating the axiom of foundation. I.e. if $\alpha$ is infinite with respect to this definition of $S$, then $S(\alpha)=\{\alpha\}=\alpha$. So $\alpha\in\alpha$, a contradiction.

Comment: @user1: Your argument seems confused. Certainly, you are correct that having $\{a\}=a$ would violate the axiom of foundation. But there is nothing wrong in an axiom of infinity relying on $S(w)=\{w\}$. Naïvely, this establishes the existence of $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\ldots\}$, which is a perfectly fine set. The customary definition is more convenient, that is all.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Of course! I was imagining $A$ would be a singleton under this definition for some reason. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Originally, ZF had 0={}, 1={{}}={0}, 2={{{}}}={1}, ....  For some reason, it must have been found not to be a very workable definition. I prefer the more straightforward Peano axioms as a basis for the natural numbers. Much more intuitive.

Answer (score 5):

*Morally speaking*[1] the Axiom of Foundation we can aid us in showing that for each positive natural number $m$ (existing in the meta-theory) and every set $x$ the set $$S^{(m)} ( x ) = \overbrace{S ( \cdots ( S}^{m\text{ times}} ( x ) ) \cdots )$$ is distinct from $x$.  We first show by induction (I guess in the meta-theory) that $x \in S^{(m)}(x)$ for all $m \geq 1$, and then note that by Foundation $x \notin x$, and so each $S^{(m)}(x)$ must differ from $x$.

It then follows that the sets $\varnothing$, $S(\varnothing)$, $S ( S ( \varnothing ) )$, $\ldots$ are pairwise distinct.  Since your inductive set $X$ must contain all of these, that set must be infinite (at least from the point-of-view of the meta-theory).

***Added:*** An alternative approach, done through the exercises in Ch.1 of Jech's *Set Theory*, is to define a set $N$ to be the smallest inductive set (*i.e.*, the intersection of all inductive subsets of some given inductive set), and then show that the elements of $N$ have certain properties that then imply the infiniteness (non-finiteness?) of $N$.  It is somewhat tedious (since it avoids overtly mentioning ordinals, and in particular $\omega$), but is also clean and without circularity.  Once ordinals are defined, it turns out that $N$ is actually $\omega$ (what a surprise!).

---

[1] By which I mean that there may be inaccuracies in what I am about to say, but the gist is pretty close to the actual truth.  I thank Prof. Sy David Friedman for putting this phrasing into my mathematical vocabulary.

Comment: If you start with $0=\varnothing$ then you don't need foundations.

Comment: @Asaf: True, but then pickles won't arrive when you want them to.  (I've got a few willing participants in the Great 2013 Massive Pickle Exchange.)

Comment: You mean the Young Spreewaldhof Transporters 2013 conference? :-)

Comment: I'm confused. How are you using induction before having the natural numbers?

Comment: @GitGud: The principle of induction is built into the natural numbers. Think of the natural numbers as being the smallest set containing $\emptyset$ and being closed under $S$, and you have induction for free.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen That's exactly how I'm thinking about the natural numbers. I'm seeing circularity everywhere. I can't not see circularity here. I'll take a look at this later after I clear my memory of this thoughts.

Comment: @GitGud:  Though what I said is perhaps slightly inaccurate, the gist is basically correct.  I can think about the natural numbers as existing in the meta-theory, and having the usual properties there.  I guess I then only get a "meta-theorem" that inductive sets are infinite.  (As Asaf notes, one can get around this difficulty, and exercises in Ch.1 of Jech's _Set Theory_ do basically this _without_ first defining what ordinals are.  You show that the elements of the smallest iductive set have certain properties, which then implies the non-finiteness of that set.)

Comment: @GutGud: One _can_ avoid all of the problems that you see with potential circularity.  But I feel it is neither intuitive nor enlightening.  The basic idea is what I originally wrote.  An very broad outline of the more technical approach is now present in the latest revision.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: @GitGud: If you stop spinning in your chair you might see less circularity! It could help with the nausea and seasickness too! :-)

Comment: @ArthurFischer You may enjoy reading this: http://cheng.staff.shef.ac.uk/morality/morality.pdf *Mathematics, morally*, by E. Cheng.

Answer (score 4):

The intuition comes from the definition of the von Neumann ordinals. We define an ordinal as the set of its predecessors, which means that the successor ordinal of $\alpha$ is exactly $\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$.

The finite ordinals corresponds to the natural numbers, so we can easily define $0=\varnothing$ and $n+1=n\cup\{n\}$. The axiom of infinity is equivalent to saying that there is a set whose members are exactly all the finite ordinals.

Answer (score 0):

With Extensionality, Power Set, and Separation, [a signleton exists](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/snex.html). All {∅}, {{∅}}, {{{∅}}}, ..., are of cardinality 1. You cannot generate an infinite set/class this way.

Class *A* is ordinal (written as [Ord *A*](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/df-ord.html)) iff *A* is transitive and is well-ordered by the epsilon relation. Define the class of all ordinal numbers On = { *x* | Ord *x* }.

With neither Infinity nor Regularity, \eqref{ordom} and \eqref{ordeleqon} are provable.
$$ \operatorname{Ord} \omega \tag{1} \label{ordom} $$
$$ \operatorname{Ord} A \leftrightarrow \left( A \in \mathrm{On} \lor A = \mathrm{On} \right) \tag{2} \label{ordeleqon} $$

Consequently, [ω ∈ On ∨ ω = On](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/omon.html). If ω is not a member of On, ω = On, which [does not exist](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/onprc.html). Converse this proposition. [If ω exists, it is an ordinal number.](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/omelon2.html)
$$ \omega \in \mathrm V \to \omega \in \mathrm{On} $$

The Axiom of Infinity asserts [the existence of ω](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/omex.html).
$$ \omega \in \mathrm V $$

A finitist **denies** existence of ω. This leads to [ω = On](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/fineqv.html). A finitist can develop natural number, integer, and rational number arithmetic but be denied the real numbers (as well as much of the rest of mathematics).